# Laravel fetch data from model where the condtions is from another model

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I have a table called List which i planned to be displayed into view with this command : `$lists= List::with('user', 'product.photodb', 'tagCloud.tagDetail')->get();`. But, i want the data displayed is only those that has TagID equal to the one user inputted. Those data can be retrieved from TagCloud table.

What i am currently doing is :

```
$clouds = TagCloud::select('contentID')
                  ->where('tagDetailID', '=', $tagID)
                  ->get();

$lists = List::with('user', 'product.photodb', 'tagCloud.tagDetail')
             ->where('id', '=', $clouds->contentID)
             ->get();
```

But when i tried to run it, it only return a null value, even though when i am doing `return $clouds`, it does returned the desired ID.

Where did i do wrong ? Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of gotchas with your current solution.

1. Using `get()` returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object. Hence you can't use `$clouds->contentID` directly since `$clouds` is a collection (or array if you prefer). [See Collection Documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections)
2. `where(...)` expects the third parameter to be a **string** or **integer**, aka single value. Instead, you are passing a `collection`, which won't work.

The correct way is to use `whereHas()` which allows you to filter through an eager loaded relationship.

**Final Code:**

```
$lists = List::with('user', 'product.photodb', 'tagCloud.tagDetail')
            ->whereHas('tagCloud',function($query) use ($tagID) {
                return $query->where('contentID','=',$tagID);
            })
            ->get();
```

[See `WhereHas` Documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `whereHas()`

```
$list = List::with(...)
    ->whereHas('relation', function($q) use($id) {
        return $q->where('id', $id);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Where condition in you tagCloud model method tagDetail

```
public function tagDetail(){
    return $q->where('id', $id);
}
```